# Save large files from php stdin

Tags: php, post, stream

Advise me the most optimal way to save large files from php stdin, please.
iOS developer sends me large video content to server and i have to store it in to files.

I read the stdin thread with video data and write it to the file. For example, in this way:

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");    
while (!feof($handle)) {
      $http_raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
```

What function is better to use? file_get_contents or fread or something else?

Comment: If you can influence the upload process I would suggest to send it as multipart form data. It would be available via $_FILES this way and the web server itself would handle the upload of the file and save it to filesystem. expecting this the most performant way.

Comment: hek2mgl, thanks for your answer. In future we'll try to remake uploading proccess with mime functionality, but now we are wanting to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `file_get_contents` because it would attempt to load all the content of the file into a string

[FROM PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

Am sure you just want to create the movie file on your server .. this is a more efficient way

```
$in = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$out = fopen('largefile.dat', 'w');

while ( ! feof($in) ) {
    fwrite($out, fread($in, 8192));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @hek2mgl that treating this as a multipart form upload would make most sense, but if you can't alter your input interface then you can use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) on a stream instead of looping through the file yourself.

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");  
if (false === file_put_contents("outputfile.dat", $handle))
{
  // handle error
}
fclose($handle);
```

It's cleaner than iterating through the file, and it might be faster (I haven't tested).

Answer (score 0):

If you use nginx as web server i want to recommend [nginx upload module](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html) with possibility to resume upload.