# how to download big file (> 250 MB) in php?

Tags: php

I have a script that allow user to download file with filesize > 250MB. When the filesize is < 100MB, it's downloadable. But not with file > 250 MB.

```
I have changed the setting in php.ini:
memory_limit = 12800M
post_max_size = 8000M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
max_execution_time = 512000
```

But still it's not workable. How to make it so that i can download file with > 250MB ?

**Update: code to download the zip file**

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 512000);

$file_folder = "image/data/";   // folder to load files

$zip = new ZipArchive();            // Load zip library 
$zip_name = "image.zip";            // Zip name
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){       // Opening zip file to load files
    echo  "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time<br/>";
}

$dir = opendir ("image/data");
$counter = 0;
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) 
{
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..')
    {   }else
    {
        $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file, $file);
    }
}

$zip->close();

// push to download the zip
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_name));
readfile($zip_name);
// remove zip file is exists in temp path
unlink($zip_name);
```

Comment: By using apache's mod_xsendfile: https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Comment: You can split files into smaller parts and download

Comment: erm, i cant split it bcos i read data from the existing folder and download it in zip folder

Comment: You'll need to show some code and tell us what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: @Pekka웃 the question has been updated.

Comment: @Twisted1919 how to use the XSENDFILE? any sample?

Comment: See [my earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596116/caching-http-responses-when-they-are-dynamically-created-by-php/10596231#10596231) on this subject.

Comment: You'll need to be able to reconfigure your server to use `x-sendfile`. What goes wrong with the download, what happens?

Comment: when the file is > 250MB, what i get is 0 kb. So can be said the zip folder is damaged.

Comment: Is the file completely empty when you look inside? It may contain a PHP error message.

Comment: yes, it's completely empty. To be exactly, it cant be opened. It says the archive is either in unknown format or damaged.

Comment: It can't be opened with the zip app but it can be using a text editor.

Comment: You'll be much better of using CURL

Comment: @Chibueze I don't see how curl plays into this at all. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't get why he's meddling with Apache instead of downloading using conventional methods like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16971351/612717). A `wget` command with  exec is even better than that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..so now i can get my file to be downloaded. But, once i want to extract the zip file, error  msg is given, saying that: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged. I check the copy of the zip file in the original folder n try to extract, it works fine. No problem in extracting the data. Below is the script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$file_folder = "image/data/";

$zip = new ZipArchive();    // Load zip library 
$zip_name = "image.zip";             // Zip name
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){       // Opening zip file to load files
    echo  "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time<br/>";
}

$dir = opendir ("image/data");
$counter = 0;
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) 
{
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..')
    {   }else
    {
        $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file, $file);
    }
}

$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name)){

    // set headers push to download the zip
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zip_name)); 

    //readfile($zip_name);
    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    //unlink($zip_name);

    $fp = @fopen($zip_name, "rb");
    if ($fp) {
     while(!feof($fp)) {
         echo fread($fp, 1024);
         flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
         if (connection_status()!=0) {
             @fclose($zip_name);
             die();
         }
     }
     @fclose($zip_name);
    }
    unlink($zip_name);
}
```

the File size that I retrieve is also correct. What is the problem?